# Creating a shape from the intersection of two shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I created this leaf shape by drawing two circles on the same layer using the "intersect shape areas" setting.

[image]

The leaf "shape" is still treated as two circles - photoshop just shows the portion where the 2 circles are intersecting. Is there a way to turn that intersection into a actual single shape? Like this (drawn quickly but you get the idea):

[image: image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Merge Shape Components after you've intersected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the area with the magic wand tool right click and make a copy...boom you have separate layer with that shape.

Comment: Does not work. Magic wand tool can't be used on a shape layer. Besides I'm looking for the end result to be a shape (vector).

Comment: Why not rastersize shapes import to illustrator image trace then you have vectors?

Comment: why rasterize, illustrator actually knows how to do intersections of shapes